# Android - How to use menu option on mobiles which doesn't have a menu button?

Tags: android

I have a project which uses the mobile's menu button. but some mobiles don't have an option to get the menu [ex: Moto G] instead they use action bar but that's not supported on Android 2.1. I want the menu to work on both Android 2.1 as well as 4.4 how do i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is article you need to read: [Say Goodbye to the Menu Button](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html)

> If your app runs on a device without a dedicated Menu button, the
>   system decides whether to add the action overflow to the navigation
>   bar based on which API levels you declare to support in the 
>   manifest element. The logic boils down to:
>
> If you set either minSdkVersion or targetSdkVersion to 11 or higher,
>   the system will not add the legacy overflow button.
>
> Otherwise, the system will add the legacy overflow button when running
>   on Android 3.0 or higher.
>
> The only exception is that if you set minSdkVersion to 10 or lower,
>   set targetSdkVersion to 11, 12, or 13, and you do not use ActionBar,
>   the system will add the legacy overflow button when running your app
>   on a handset with Android 4.0 or higher.

Answer (score 1):

2 ways to Achieve this:

Create a button (say menu) and add it to the Action Bar. Implement your own method (Eg: Spinner) to display the options as a drop down once the button is clicked which serves as menu.

The other way is to create a context Menu

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom button and call `openOptionsMenu();` when is clicked.

Edit:

Disable the default settings button on the action bar and add this one

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/settings_button"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <View
        android:layout_width="5dp"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="5dp"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="5dp"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: That would spoil the whole UI :(

Answer (score 0):

Why not using the support library v7, which contains support action bar (which inclueds menu buttons on actionb bar) with AppCompat theme. You will have action bar with menu buttons for versions lower than 3.0. It will work from Android 2.1.

Read [THIS](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7) about Support Library v7.

And check [THIS](http://android-er.blogspot.com.es/2013/12/create-dummy-app-extend.html) example on how to make an application using AppCompat Theme.